# JavaFX trouble with TableView listener

Tags: javafx, tableview, listener, fxml

So I'm pretty new to JavaFX and have been struggling getting a listener to work properly on my TableView. I've found several different examples, but none seem to work they way I expect, or there's a problem somewhere else in my code that is preventing it from working.

Here's the snippet of the listener code in my initialize method:

```
bookList.addListener((Change<? extends LibraryBook> c) -> {
           while (c.next()) {
               if (c.wasAdded()) {
                   MainController.getInstance().setFieldChange(true);
               }
               if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                   MainController.getInstance().setFieldChange(true);
               }
               if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                   MainController.getInstance().setFieldChange(true);
               }
           }
    });

    tvLibraryTable.setItems(bookList);
    bookName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("book"));
    quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));
```

My observableList is currently initialized in my constructor (but I've moved it around a few other places as well:

```
if(library.getBooks() != null) {
        this.newList = new ArrayList<LibraryBook>(library.getBooks());
        this.bookList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(library.getBooks());
```

So in the rest of my controller view, I've got buttons to add and remove books from the list, and if you double click on an item in the list you can update the quantity. I'm using custom modal dialogue boxes for all these options. When I return the results from the dialogue box, I update my bookList and I think that's where my problem might be. Here's my full code for the controller class. And I'm pretty sure the code is pretty rough, but it's functional at the moment...minus the tableview listener.

```
package app;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.util.Pair;
import javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import models.Book;
import models.Library;
import models.LibraryBook;
import models.ValidationException;
import view.ViewType;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
public class LibraryDetailViewController implements Initializable {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    private Library library;
    private Library origLibrary;
    private List<LibraryBook> newList;
    private ObservableList<LibraryBook> bookList;

    @FXML private TextField tfLibrary;
    @FXML private TableView<LibraryBook> tvLibraryTable;
    @FXML private TableColumn<LibraryBook, Book> bookName;
    @FXML private TableColumn<LibraryBook, Integer> quantity;
    @FXML private ComboBox<Book> cbBook;
    @FXML private Button saveButton, auditTrail, inventoryReport, addBook, deleteBook;
    @FXML private Label saveLabel;

    public LibraryDetailViewController(Library library) {
        this.library = library;
        this.origLibrary = new Library(library);
        if(library.getBooks() != null) {
            this.newList = new ArrayList<LibraryBook>(library.getBooks());
            this.bookList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(library.getBooks());
        } else {
            this.newList =  new ArrayList<LibraryBook>();
            this.bookList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        }
    }

    //event handler for buttons
    @FXML private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();

        if (source == saveButton) {
            try {
                saveLibraryFields();
                saveLabel.setText(library.saveLibrary(origLibrary));
                origLibrary = library;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e);
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setHeaderText("Save Error");
                alert.setContentText("Error saving data. Please check fields and try again.");
                alert.showAndWait();
                //revert to original model data on error
                library = origLibrary;
            } catch (ValidationException e) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setHeaderText(e.getMessage());
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        } else if(source == auditTrail) {
            if(library.getId() == 0) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setHeaderText("Audit Trail Error");
                alert.setContentText("No audit trail exists! Please save the library first.");
                alert.showAndWait();
            } else {
                MainController.getInstance().changeView(ViewType.LIBRARY_AUDITTRAIL, library);
            }
        } else if(source == inventoryReport) {
            try {
                createPdf("Inventory Report.pdf");
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Success");
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("The report has been created!");
                alert.showAndWait();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(source == addBook) {

            // create modal dialogue box
            List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(MainController.getInstance().getBookGateway().getBooks());
            Dialog<Pair<Book, String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
            dialog.setTitle("Book List");
            dialog.setHeaderText("Add a book to the library");

            dialog.setGraphic(new ImageView(this.getClass().getResource("/view/book-stack.png").toString()));

            ButtonType okButtonType = new ButtonType("Ok", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
            dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(okButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);


            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            grid.setHgap(10);
            grid.setVgap(10);
            grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

            ObservableList<Book> bookListOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList(books);
            ChoiceBox<Book> cbBooks = new ChoiceBox<Book>(bookListOptions);
            TextField tfQuantity = new TextField();
            tfQuantity.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new NumberStringConverter()));
            tfQuantity.setPromptText("Quantity");

            grid.add(new Label("Please select a book"), 0, 0);
            grid.add(cbBooks, 1, 0);
            grid.add(new Label("Please enter a quantity"), 0, 1);
            grid.add(tfQuantity, 1, 1);

            dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

            // convert results that were selected
            dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
                if (dialogButton == okButtonType) {
                    return new Pair<>(cbBooks.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), tfQuantity.getText());
                }
                return null;
            });

            // return results of dialogue box to main view and reinitialize tableView list
            Optional<Pair<Book, String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();
            result.ifPresent(book -> {
                    newList.add(new LibraryBook(book.getKey(), Integer.parseInt(book.getValue()), true));
                    library.setBooks(newList);
                    bookList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(library.getBooks());
                    bookName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("book"));
                    quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));
                    tvLibraryTable.setItems(bookList);
            });
        } else if(source == deleteBook) {
            newList.remove(tvLibraryTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            library.setBooks(newList);
            bookList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(library.getBooks());
            bookName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("book"));
            quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));
            tvLibraryTable.setItems(bookList);
        }
    }

    /**
     * event handler for double clicking a book from the ListView
     *
     * @param event
     */
    @FXML private void handleMouseClick(MouseEvent event) {
        if(event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
            if(event.getClickCount() == 2){
                if (tvLibraryTable.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()) {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
                    alert.setHeaderText("Update Quantity Error");
                    alert.setContentText("No book was selected!");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                } else {
                    LibraryBook lb = tvLibraryTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
                    dialog.setTitle("Edit Book");
                    dialog.setHeaderText("Please enter the new quantity.");
                    dialog.setContentText("Quantity:");

                    Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
                    result.ifPresent(quantity -> {
                        lb.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantity));
                        tvLibraryTable.refresh();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveLibraryDetail() {
        try {
            saveLibraryFields();
            library.saveLibrary(origLibrary);
            origLibrary = library;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            library = origLibrary;
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(e.getMessage());
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    public void saveLibraryFields() {
        library.setLibraryName(tfLibrary.getText());
        library.setBooks(tvLibraryTable.getItems());
    }

    private class MyFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {
        Font ffont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 18, Font.ITALIC);

        public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
            Phrase header = new Phrase(library.getLibraryName(), ffont);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    header,
                    (document.right() - document.left()) / 2 + document.leftMargin(),
                    document.top() + 10, 0);
        }
    }

    public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        MyFooter event = new MyFooter();
        writer.setPageEvent(event);

        document.open();

        //create table with 4 evenly-spaced columns
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
        table.addCell("Title:");
        table.addCell("Author:");
        table.addCell("Publisher:");
        table.addCell("Quantity:");
        table.setHeaderRows(1);
        table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        for(int aw = 0; aw < library.getBooks().size(); aw++){
            table.addCell(library.getBooks().get(aw).getBook().getTitle());
            table.addCell(library.getBooks().get(aw).getBook().getAuthor().getFullName());
            table.addCell(library.getBooks().get(aw).getBook().getPublisher());
            table.addCell(String.valueOf(library.getBooks().get(aw).getQuantity()));
            table.completeRow();
        }
        document.add(table);

        document.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        //init field values
        tfLibrary.setText(library.getLibraryName());

        /*if(library.getBooks() != null) {
            ObservableList<LibraryBook> booksList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(library.getBooks());
            bookName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("book"));
            quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));
            tvLibraryTable.setItems(booksList);
        }*/

        //event listeners for field changes
        if(library.getId() == 0) {
            MainController.getInstance().setFieldChange(true);
        }

        tfLibrary.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                            String oldValue, String newValue) {
                MainController.getInstance().setFieldChange(true);
            }
        });

        /**
         *  Unable to get listener for tableview to work properly :(
         *
        ObservableList<LibraryBook> bookList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(book ->
            new Observable[] {
                (Observable) book.getBook(),
                book.getObsQuantity()
            });
        */
        bookList.addListener((Change<? extends LibraryBook> c) -> {
               while (c.next()) {
                   if (c.wasAdded()) {
                       MainController.getInstance().setFieldChange(true);
                   }
                   if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                       MainController.getInstance().setFieldChange(true);
                   }
                   if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                       MainController.getInstance().setFieldChange(true);
                   }
               }
        });

        tvLibraryTable.setItems(bookList);
        bookName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("book"));
        quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));
    }
}
```

And here's my fxml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="pane-bg" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="106.0" layoutY="63.0" text="Library Name:">
         <font>
            <Font name="Serif Regular" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="saveButton" layoutX="465.0" layoutY="126.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Save">
         <font>
            <Font name="Serif Regular" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <TextField fx:id="tfLibrary" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="61.0" />
      <Label fx:id="saveLabel" layoutX="431.0" layoutY="277.0" textFill="#f20909">
         <font>
            <Font name="Serif Regular" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="auditTrail" layoutX="440.0" layoutY="170.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="View Audit Trail" />
      <TableView fx:id="tvLibraryTable" editable="true" layoutX="174.0" layoutY="104.0" onMouseClicked="#handleMouseClick" prefHeight="215.0" prefWidth="248.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="bookName" prefWidth="169.0" text="Book Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="quantity" prefWidth="77.0" text="Quantity" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button fx:id="inventoryReport" layoutX="437.0" layoutY="215.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Inventory Report" />
      <Button fx:id="addBook" layoutX="174.0" layoutY="325.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Add Book">
         <font>
            <Font name="Serif Regular" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="deleteBook" layoutX="331.0" layoutY="325.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Delete Book">
         <font>
            <Font name="Serif Regular" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <!-- <Button fx:id="backToListButton" layoutX="309.0" layoutY="286.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Back to Author List" /> -->
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You don't need a listener.  As far as I can tell, all you are doing is maintaining multiple lists and trying to keep them in synch with a listener.  You can just use one list and remove the listener and all of the other lists (e.g. have library.getBooks() return an ObservableList<LibraryBook>), use that everywhere, remove newList and BookList (and origLibrary, you only need one library) and you are probably 90 percent of the way there.  It's a bit too much code for somebody to replicate in an answer, an [mcve] might get a better response.

Comment: Also, you appear to be implementing a controller (specifically, `MainController`) as a singleton, which is possible, but a little technical and might not be working the way you think. So a [MCVE] would definitely be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to reduce the problem to the instructions you shared. The reason I need the listener, is so that if the user tries to switch to another view without saving the changes to the table, they are given a warning and the option to save the changes or continue to another view without saving.